# How to call a fuseki server endpoint from a Clojure Program?

Tags: clojure, sparql, jena, semantic-web, fuseki

I would like to call fuseki server endpoint and create a model from my Clojure program. Is there a library in Clojure for fuseki or shld I call Apache Jena Java library, if so can you pls tell me how as I'm new to Clojure. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some fairly straightforward googling suggests that Seabass may be of interest.

https://github.com/ryankohl/seabass/

This is a wrapping of Jena.